# Query an xml (stored in varchar) in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a database table which is structured as shown below :

```
TransactionId   Product   ErrorXML(stored as varchar)
```

The ErrorXML has the structure below :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <GetResponse
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
    <Error>   
     <ErrorCode>1809</ErrorCode>    
    <Description>Could not generate transaction.</Description>  
    </Error>  
    <Success>false</Success>  
    <ContractNumber />  
      </GetResponse>
```

I would like to write a query to extract the ErrorCode element and ErrorDescription element for each of the Errorxml row .
Is there a way I can do it ?

I did some research and tried writing a query something like this and it wouldnt work , gives out a null:

```
select  CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),ErrorXML)).value('(/GetResponse/Error/Description)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as ErrorDescription
from ErrorLog E
```

Comment: You have to use the `nodes()` syntax to shred an xml data type instance into relational data. => http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hey shiva . Thanks ! You know what.. I have an xml but its stored in a varchar datatype. I know its not a good practice ,but thats how its being stored currently. I am not sure if hte node() would apply , but will give it a try..Thanks !

Comment: I updated my answer for your situation (`XML` stored in `VARCHAR` datatype) with a working example in SQL Fiddle. Check it out.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de703/3)</kbd>

#### The Output

```
ErrorCode   ErrorDescription
1809        Could not generate transaction.
2119        Credit Card Overlimit.Payment Failed.
```

#### The SQL

See the SQL fiddle for why we have to use a TABLE variable due to your data being in VARCHAR and not XML datatype.

```
--SELECT * FROM Transactions

DECLARE @ErrorDataTable TABLE
(
    ErrorXml XML NOT NULL,
    ErrorCode NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    ErrorDescription NVARCHAR(200) NULL
)

INSERT 
INTO @ErrorDataTable(ErrorXml)
SELECT
    CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),T.ErrorXML))
FROM Transactions T

-- SELECT * FROM @ErrorDataTable

SELECT
     T.c.value('ErrorCode[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as ErrorCode
     , T.c.value('Description[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as ErrorDescription    
FROM  @ErrorDataTable e
    OUTER APPLY e.ErrorXml.nodes('/GetResponse/Error') T(c);
```

#### Previous Answer (deprecated)

Following Works. I'll try to put a SQLFiddle together.

```
DECLARE @ErrorXML as VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @x as XML;

SET @ErrorXML ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <GetResponse
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
    <Error>   
     <ErrorCode>1809</ErrorCode>    
    <Description>Could not generate transaction.</Description>  
    </Error>  
    <Success>false</Success>  
    <ContractNumber />  
      </GetResponse>';

SET @x = CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),@ErrorXML))

SELECT
     T.c.value('ErrorCode[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as ErrorCode
     , T.c.value('Description[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as ErrorDescription    
FROM   @x.nodes('/GetResponse/Error') T(c);
```

#### RESULTS:

```
ErrorCode   ErrorDescription
1809        Could not generate transaction.
```

Comment: can this be applied on table..I tried to do this but does not work for mw, I passed an xml string stored in varchar and tried to extract few elements but it does not work..

Comment: What is T.c.value and T(c) refer to?